# How to delete all sample data magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, sample-data

How can we delete all the magento sample data imported before the installation using the magentosample data sql file.

Magento sample data delete includes deletion of sample products , sample categories and also sample test orders.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Quickest way would be to use direct queries.
Remember to put `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` at the start of the queries and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;` at the end.

**products**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_option_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_bundle_selection`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_tier_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_attribute_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_link_type`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_price`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_title`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_option_type_value`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_label`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_attribute`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_super_link`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_enabled_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_website`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `cataloginventory_stock`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `rating_option_vote`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `rating_option_vote_aggregated`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `review`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_detail`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_entity_summary`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `review_store`;
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_type`(`link_type_id`,`code`) VALUES (1,'relation'),(2,'bundle'),(3,'super'),(4,'up_sell'),(5,'cross_sell');
INSERT  INTO `catalog_product_link_attribute`(`product_link_attribute_id`,`link_type_id`,`product_link_attribute_code`,`data_type`) VALUES (1,2,'qty','decimal'),(2,1,'position','int'),(3,4,'position','int'),(4,5,'position','int'),(6,1,'qty','decimal'),(7,3,'position','int'),(8,3,'qty','decimal');
INSERT  INTO `cataloginventory_stock`(`stock_id`,`stock_name`) VALUES (1,'Default');
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_product_entity`;
```

**categories**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;

INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity`(`entity_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_set_id`,`parent_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`path`,`POSITION`,`level`,`children_count`) VALUES (1,3,0,0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1',1,0,1),(2,3,3,0,'2009-02-20 00:25:34','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1/2',1,1,0);
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_int`(`value_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,3,32,0,2,1),(2,3,32,1,2,1);
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar`(`value_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,3,31,0,1,'Root Catalog'),(2,3,33,0,1,'root-catalog'),(3,3,31,0,2,'Default Category'),(4,3,39,0,2,'PRODUCTS'),(5,3,33,0,2,'default-category');

/**** Magento ver. 1.6.x.x ****/

TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;

INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity`(`entity_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_set_id`,`parent_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`path`,`POSITION`,`level`,`children_count`) VALUES (1,3,0,0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','1',1,0,1), (2,3,3,1,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','0000-00-00 00:00:00','1/2','1','1','0');
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_int`(`value_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,3,32,0,2,1),(2,3,36,0,2,1),(3,3,61,0,2,1),(4,3,44,0,2,NULL),(5,3,45,0,2,1),(6,3,62,0,2,1),(7,3,63,0,2,1),(8,3,64,0,2,NULL);
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar`(`value_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,3,31,0,1,'Root Catalog'),(2,3,35,0,2,'Default Category'),(3,3,37,0,2,'default-category'),(4,3,40,0,2,NULL),(5,3,43,0,2,'PRODUCTS'),(6,3,52,0,2,NULL),(7,3,55,0,2,NULL);
```

**sales**

```
TRUNCATE `sales_order`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_order_datetime`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_order_decimal`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_datetime`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_decimal`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_int`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_text`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_order_entity_varchar`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_order_int`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_order_text`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_order_varchar`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`;
  TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`;
  TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`;
  TRUNCATE `tag`;
  TRUNCATE `tag_relation`;
  TRUNCATE `tag_summary`;
  TRUNCATE `wishlist`;
  TRUNCATE `log_quote`;
  TRUNCATE `report_event`;

  ALTER TABLE `sales_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_order_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_order_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_order_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_order_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_order_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_order_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_order_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_order_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_order_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_order_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_order_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `sendfriend_log` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `tag` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `tag_relation` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `tag_summary` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `wishlist` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `log_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

**customers**

```
TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity`;
  TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_datetime`;
  TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_decimal`;
  TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_int`;
  TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_text`;
  TRUNCATE `customer_address_entity_varchar`;
  TRUNCATE `customer_entity`;
  TRUNCATE `customer_entity_datetime`;
  TRUNCATE `customer_entity_decimal`;
  TRUNCATE `customer_entity_int`;
  TRUNCATE `customer_entity_text`;
  TRUNCATE `customer_entity_varchar`;
  TRUNCATE `log_customer`;
  TRUNCATE `log_visitor`;
  TRUNCATE `log_visitor_info`;

  ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `customer_entity` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_datetime` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_decimal` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_int` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_text` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `customer_entity_varchar` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `log_customer` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `log_visitor` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
  ALTER TABLE `log_visitor_info` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

  -- Now, lets Reset all ID counters
  TRUNCATE `eav_entity_store`;
  ALTER TABLE  `eav_entity_store` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

sources

- https://robotsystematic.com/delete-magento-products-mysql
- http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-delete-magento-test-orders-from-a-magento-store/

Comment: Can you please also suggest from where all the images can be deleted?

Comment: You can empty the `media/catalog/product` directory

Comment: any changes arrived on magento 1.9.2.3 for delete

Comment: sales_order - there is no table like this in magento - its all with _flat.

Comment: perfect answer +1 :) !!!!

Comment: @SanderMangel Like same could you share for Magento 2.3? or same we can use  Magento 2.3?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution provided by Sander Mangel above, you have to delete the contents in the underlisted directories to get rid of product images and downloadable product files

1. media/catalog/product
2. media/downloadable/files

Comment: Deleting media/wysiwyg can cause the removal of images uploaded via backend for Banners or other places.