# Delete old data before migration

Tags: magento-1.8, delete

We did an export of some old transactions, products and categories some time back. However there have been multiple updates to the data so a new export is required.

In order to do so we need to way to delete all products and transactions from the current Magento setup. How can we do that?

Would a flush similiar to this work in Magento 1,8 [How to delete all sample data magento 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68749/how-to-delete-all-sample-data-magento-1-9)

Comment: If you are importing data through Magento's DataFlow it will automatically update new content for your products (if all attributes are same), for transnational you can follow the other link

Answer (score 1):

Run these script in your phpmyadmin
***********for categories********************

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_datetime`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_decimal`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_int`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_text`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_entity_varchar`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `catalog_category_product_index`;

INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity`(`entity_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_set_id`,`parent_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`,`path`,`POSITION`,`level`,`children_count`) VALUES (1,3,0,0,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1',1,0,1),(2,3,3,0,'2009-02-20 00:25:34','2009-02-20 00:25:34','1/2',1,1,0);
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_int`(`value_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,3,32,0,2,1),(2,3,32,1,2,1);
INSERT  INTO `catalog_category_entity_varchar`(`value_id`,`entity_type_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`entity_id`,`value`) VALUES (1,3,31,0,1,'Root Catalog'),(2,3,33,0,1,'root-catalog'),(3,3,31,0,2,'Default Category'),(4,3,39,0,2,'PRODUCTS'),(5,3,33,0,2,'default-category');

    *****************for customers*****************


    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- reset customers
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_datetime;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_decimal;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_int;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_text;
TRUNCATE customer_address_entity_varchar;
TRUNCATE customer_entity;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_datetime;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_decimal;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_int;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_text;
TRUNCATE customer_entity_varchar;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;

ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_datetime AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_decimal AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_int AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_text AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_address_entity_varchar AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_datetime AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_decimal AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_int AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_text AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE customer_entity_varchar AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE log_customer AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE log_visitor AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE log_visitor_info AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

For Orders

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_address`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_payment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_status_history`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_track`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_aggregated_created`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`; 
TRUNCATE `tag`; 
TRUNCATE `tag_relation`; 
TRUNCATE `tag_summary`; 
TRUNCATE `wishlist`; 
TRUNCATE `log_quote`; 
TRUNCATE `report_event`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_status_history` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

You can use this function to delete attribute sets.

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$db_read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$attribute_sets = $db_read->fetchCol("SELECT attribute_set_id FROM " . $resource->getTableName("eav_attribute_set") . " WHERE attribute_set_id<> 4 AND entity_type_id=4");
foreach ($attribute_sets as $attribute_set_id) {
    try {
        Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set")->load($attribute_set_id)->delete();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

And look for this table to remove attribute

```
catalog_eav_attribute
eav_attribute
eav_attribute_set
```

Check eav_attribute column is_user_defined so you can get some idea.
See More Here https://gist.github.com/leek/1219708